# Honda Fit gd 1 cvt suddenly won't accelerate, after how many seconds turns back to normal

Tags: honda, fit, cvt-transmission

I have encountered new problem with my car: Honda Fit gd 1 cvt.

Going home I ran into small flood (water level is not high, just around the side skirts). Every time there is a flood the car won't accelerate. RPMs already reaching 4k. After how many seconds (10 secs or more) it turns back to normal. Already scanned: no issues. No dashboard errors. I'm confused because I've already encountered many floods. Worse case is O2 sensor gets wet I think, and there is the error from dashboard. I just removed the battery and the CEL disappears. Today is different. It occurs many times and no errors. Water level is not that high. 
**What is the possible problem?** I'm afraid it may getting even more worse.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Check the level and condition of the CVT fluid, and consider replacing it. I believe the transmission has a breather pipe and I wonder if it might be possible for water to enter. The GD1's CVT has an automated clutch rather than a torque converter, but the early start clutches were rather notorious for poor grip due to unsuitable transmission fluid being used in the early days.

When [checking the CVT fluid level](http://www.hondafitjazz.com/manual/a00/html/02/saa2e02e15100013001maat00.html), do so on level ground and between 60 and 90 seconds of turning the engine off.

You could try conducting a [CVT stall speed test](http://www.hondafitjazz.com/manual/a00/html/92/saa2e92e15117656881feat00.html):

1. Warm up the car (by driving is usually quickest).
2. Park the car, apply the parking brake, and chock the front wheels.
3. Start the engine, and ensure the A/C is off.
4. Put the transmission in D, and fully press the brake pedal and accelerator for 6-8 seconds. Note the engine speed. Allow two minutes for cooling.
5. Repeat step 4 using the S, L, and R positions.

In D and R, the specification is 2500 RPM, with a service limit of 2350-2650 RPM.

In S and L, the specification is 3000 RPM, with a service limit of 2800-3100 RPM.

For a complete CVT troubleshooting procedure, see [CVT Symptom Troubleshooting on hondafitjazz.com](http://www.hondafitjazz.com/manual/a00/html/m2/saa2em2e15100000000hbat00.html).

Also, look around the engine bay and transmission for where water intrusion or damage might occur. The crankshaft position sensor is mounted quite low on the back of the engine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Honda CVTs have one, but it sounds like the belt connecting the engine to the transmission is slipping. Is there any scheduled maintenance item in the manual for replacing it after a certain mileage or time period? If water got in there, that could also cause some slipping.

Comment: Idk sir. I bought the car 2nd hand, no manual included. I just do regular change oil and cvtf oil. The mileage is almost 150k km. Is the cause of slipping is the water? Could this be lead to worse problem? Thank you

Comment: If it is the CVT belt, it will lead to your transmission not being connected to the engine, i.e. your car won't move.

Comment: I'd recommend taking it to a Honda dealer. They will perform the recommended maintenance and can check out your transmission. It might be something as simple as it needing new transmission fluid.

Comment: This only happens, while the car is submerged in water at the door saddle. A slipping cvt chain, or a non expanding belt would always be evident. But nonetheless the problem lies at the torque converter and cvt box.